# Как убрать пробелы в поле?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Привет. Есть поле типа nchar(50). Но в конце поля очень много пробелов, если удалить их вручную, то ничего не сохранится. Пытаюсь сделать так -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Сотрудники] (
[Id]            INT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Имя]           NCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
TRIM([Фамилия])       NCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Отчество]      NCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Дата рождения] DATE        NOT NULL,
[Должность]     INT         NOT NULL,
[Отдел]         INT         NOT NULL,
[Город]         NCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Адрес]         NCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Телефон]       NCHAR (15)  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
```

Чтобы потом обновить базу данных и пробелы пропали, но появляется куча ошибок, значит убрать их не получится? 
Тогда такой запрос -

```
SELECT * FROM [Сотрудники] WHERE TRIM(Фамилия) = 'Варнавский'
```

Но он тоже не работает. Ошибок нет, просто никаких результатов не дает.
Как убрать пробелы?

Comment: тип данных nchar фиксированной длины, он автоматически дополняется пробелами до 50 символов. если вам нужны значения переменной длины используйте varchar (nvarchar). Вообще поля фиксированной длины используются крайне редко, когда вы точно знаете что в поле хранится определенное кол-во символов, не больше, но и не меньше

Comment: @Mike спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 2):

Поля с типом `(N)CHAR` всегда дополняются пробелами до максимальной длины (right-padded).
Надо заменить тип поля на `(N)VARCHAR`.

Тип `CHAR` применяйте только к полям хранящим значения постоянной длины, например, хэш.